# SQL search query returns 'Syntax error in FROM clause'

Tags: sql

Im a beginner and trying to learn SQL. On an exercise I was doing I entered the following query and got an error 'Syntax error in FROM clause'

```
select orders.customerid, customers.customername, count(orders.customerid)
from orders
join customers on customers.customerid = orders.customerid
group by orders.customerid
order by count(orders.customerid)
```

Comment: Which RDBMS?  Assuming `mysql`, I see no problem with the posted sql -- http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0b36/1...  If you're using another database, then you need to include `customername` in your `group by` clause (but I think that would receive a different error).

Comment: group by orders.customerid, customers.customername

Comment: could need `group by orders.customerid, customers.customername` (in th newer mysql transitive dependancies are honoured, in postgres they are not)

Comment: I'm at this website: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

Comment: I put in that code and got the syntax error in from clause

Comment: The `sql` you posted runs on that site for me . . .

Comment: I tried replacing group by orders.customerid, customers.customername and i still have the same error

Comment: I tried using different browsers. it must be something else

Comment: `select orders.customerid, MIN(customers.customername), count(orders.customerid)` would probably work.

Comment: I try different browsers all the time. I must be very confused.

Comment: i just tried a different computer, a mac, STILL THE SAME PROBLEM! Wth can anyone help?

Comment: Correct ANSI/ISO SQL syntax! (http://developer.mimer.com/validator/parser200x/index.tml says "Conforms to Core SQL-2003")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the W3Schools SQL thingy the type of join  used with the `join` keyword needs to be specified (inner, left, right).

Using `join customers on customers.customerid = orders.customerid` gives the error you got *Syntax error in FROM clause.*

Changing the join to an `inner join` fixes that error, but there's still another issue, the missing column in the group by statement: *You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'customername' as part of an aggregate function.*

After you fix that the query would look like:

```
select orders.customerid, customers.customername, count(orders.customerid)
from orders
inner join customers on customers.customerid = orders.customerid
group by orders.customerid, customers.customername
order by count(orders.customerid);
```

However, if you want to return all customers regardless if the have any orders you should change the query to use a left join:

```
select orders.customerid, customers.customername, count(orders.customerid)
from customers
left join orders on customers.customerid = orders.customerid
group by orders.customerid, customers.customername
order by count(orders.customerid);
```

On a side note, this might be a good time to pick up the use of aliases:

```
select o.customerid, c.customername, count(o.customerid) as count_of_orders
from customers as c
left join orders as o on c.customerid = o.customerid
group by o.customerid, c.customername
order by count(o.customerid);
```

See how much shorter the query became? :)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU! I can now continue learning. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Nice answer -- tested in 3 browsers and finally got the same error with Firefox.  This does seem to resolve the issue.  Why on earth would the browser control the engine!  +1

Comment: @sgeddes Heh, beats me; guess it's a cheap way to provide db to everyone ;)

Comment: BTW: what is a `browser`, and why would it be relevant to SQL syntax (or semantics)?

Comment: @wildplasser W3Schools uses a browser based database it seems, so I guess the browser might determine the level of standard conformance and dialect? Just speculating though, I haven't looked into it. It's relevant in this specific case, but of course wouldn't be otherwise. (More than rdbs engine is anyway)

Comment: Which DBMS requires "inner" keyword?

Comment: @jarlh Iit would seem that the database used in the W3Schools Try it yourself editor does need a qualifier like inner. Also, Microsoft Access needs inner to be specified. There are probably other implementations that does as well, even though the standard doesn't require it afaik.